# Dealing with two Python libraries from PyPi with same import name?

Tags: python-3.x

Just realized that these two Python libraries:

- [colour · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/colour/) (`pip install colour`)
- [colour-science · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/colour-science/) (`pip install colour-science`)

... use the exact same import - and are therefore in conflict:

```py
import colour
```

In my MSYS2 installation, I have noticed this:

```
$ pacman -Ss colour
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-python-colour 1~0.1.5-1
    converts and manipulates various color representation (HSL, RVB, web, X11, ...) (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-python-colour-science 0.3.16-1
    Python library for a multitude of colour science applications (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-colour 1~0.1.5-1 [installed]
    converts and manipulates various color representation (HSL, RVB, web, X11, ...) (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-colour-science 0.3.16-1
    Python library for a multitude of colour science applications (mingw-w64)
```

... and my earlier use of colour-science was gone, so I tried this:

```
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-colour-science
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: mingw-w64-x86_64-python-colour-science and mingw-w64-x86_64-python-colour are in conflict. Remove mingw-w64-x86_64-python-colour? [Y/n] y

Packages (3) mingw-w64-x86_64-python-colour-1~0.1.5-1 [removal]  mingw-w64-x86_64-python-imageio-2.9.0-2
             mingw-w64-x86_64-python-colour-science-0.3.16-1

Total Download Size:    2.66 MiB
Total Installed Size:  20.19 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      20.08 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
 mingw-w64-x86_64-python-imageio-2.9.0-2-any              379.3 KiB  1574 KiB/s 00:00 [#################################################] 100%  mingw-w64-x86_64-python-colour-science-0.3.16-1-any        2.3 MiB  2.17 MiB/s 00:01 [#################################################] 100% (2/2) checking keys in keyring                                                        [#################################################] 100% (2/2) checking package integrity                                                      [#################################################] 100% (2/2) loading package files                                                           [#################################################] 100% (2/2) checking for file conflicts                                                     [#################################################] 100% (3/3) checking available disk space                                                   [#################################################] 100% :: Processing package changes...
(1/1) removing mingw-w64-x86_64-python-colour                                         [#################################################] 100% (1/2) installing mingw-w64-x86_64-python-imageio                                      [#################################################] 100% Optional dependencies for mingw-w64-x86_64-python-imageio
    mingw-w64-x86_64-freeimage [installed]
    mingw-w64-x86_64-python-tifffile
(2/2) installing mingw-w64-x86_64-python-colour-science                               [#################################################] 100%
```

So, I cannot use both `colour` and `colour-science` libraries via `pacman` in MSYS2, which does make sense ...

But in principle - is there any way I could use both of these libraries at the same time, even if not via the package manager?